# Firebase Database - Wrong Encoding

Tags: json, firebase, encoding, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am new to Firebase and I want to use their Database, but there seems to be some issues with the encoding.
Here is my example json with UTF-8 Encoding:

```
[
 {
   "Stack": "This is madness! äüöß ",
   "Overflow": 666
 }
]
```

And this is the result, when I import the json to Firebase:

[image: Wrong Encoding in Firebase Database]

What can I do to import characters like "äüöß" to the Firebase Database?

Thank you!

Comment: Most likely, you just need to change the encoding of your database or table to UTF-8.  It looks like the correct information is already being passed into Firebase.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Firebase is a cloud-hosted database. You cannot change the encoding. All data imported/exported as JSON.

Comment: @user2738996: I just copied your JSON, pasted it into a text file in VIM, ran `firebase database:set /40668057 value.json` and it shows up perfectly fine in the Firebase Console and through the [REST API](https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/40668057.json). How did you add the JSON to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thank you for your answers.
I used the Web Console to import the json (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[projectname]/database/).

But the mistake was the encoding. I thought, because of the option in Notepad++

```
Settings --> Preferences --> New Document --> Encoding --> UTF8 (Apply to open ANSI files)
```

that my file was UTF-8 encoded. But a simple

```
Encoding --> Convert to UTF-8
```

did the trick.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am having the same issue but the text is being saved from the web browser to firebase. It's happening with a user of my app. Any idea on how to fix it from the javascript code?

Comment: Have you tried to manually encode the text to UTF8 before sending it to Firebase? Here is one resource I found: https://gist.github.com/joni/3760795/8f0c1a608b7f0c8b3978db68105c5b1d741d0446